# Apple ID no longer working on discussions.apple.com

Tags: apple-id, apple-inc

When I try and log into  discussions.apple.com I see this message:

```
"Please sign in again. For added security, we need to reconfirm your Apple ID"
```

So I do that then I see:

```
"Pick a username"
```

It says that's available and I hit continue and then I see:

```
"An account utilizing this email address already exists.  Only one account per email address is allowed on Apple Support Communities".
```

I called Apple Care and they said they weren't sure who to contact about the matter and that I should just use another email address.  Of course I prefer to continue using this email address that's worked for years on the discussion groups.  Apparently the site upgrade messed things up. What can I do to get this working?

Comment: Have your checked your Apple ID at https://appleid.apple.com/ yet?

Answer (score 2):

To get help with Apple ID, the best solution is to go to this web page to start the process:

http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/

In your case, choose contact support on the lower left of the page. Then Contact US, then iTunes store and finally Apple ID Security.

Explain in detail the error message you got and your email address that is associated with your Apple ID and your Apple ID. Give them a phone number to call you and times that work in the next week and ask for help getting a reset email sent to whatever email account is in use and preventing your participation on Apple Discussions. *Explain to them that you want to exert control / secure any and all discussion accounts that are registered to an email account that you control.*

You can also choose billing support if you are in any way not able to buy things on the iTunes store or App Stores since they don't need eligible hardware to help people that have problems spending more money without some Apple ID help.

Good luck and feel free to answer with how you sorted this out. I've done so several times in the past, but each time the steps seem to change a bit.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue .. I reported my issue using the following steps:

I opened this link:
https://getsupport.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.action

then:
[image]

then:
[image]

then:
[image]

Comment: Please ping me if you ever got an answer.